# Cntlm is not properly routing

Tags: curl

I have setup my config file like so (omitting the username, domain and password fields):

```
Username user
Domain domain
Proxy           127.0.0.1:3128
NoProxy         localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*
Listen          127.0.0.1:3128
```

I have added the PassLM, PassNT and PassNTLMMv2 lines, after having created a hash.

I run it like so:
    sudo cntlm -v -c /etc/cntlm.conf

Now, I am attempting to use curl to hit an api endpoint through the proxy server like so:

```
curl https://url -k --proxy-ntlm -u user:password --proxy 127.0.0.1:3128
```

However, I receive an error each time:
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT

I can tell that the proxy is being accessed, because cntlm spits out a long string of data after I issue the curl.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious it would not work! You put proxy and listen very same! Your file should look like this(remove all text with <> and put there your network parameters.)

```
Username <WindowsUserName>
Domain <DomainName>
Proxy           <NTLMPROXYHOST>:<NTLMPROXYPORT>
NoProxy         localhost, 127.0.0.*
Listen          3128
```

You have to give NTLM proxy Host and Port in Proxy which can not be your localhost IP.Ask your network admin for NTLM Proxy Host and port.